# Python pip upgrade error

Tags: python, pip

I want to use pip via command line: "pip install numpy"
i get the following error message:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\a
ppdata\local\temp\pip-build-vkphbn\ply
You are using pip version 7.1.2, however version 8.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' comm
and.
```

Then i tried to install the new pip-version:ython -m pip install --upgrade pip' --> but get the following error message:

```
   Collecting pip
      Using cached pip-8.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
    Installing collected packages: pip
      Found existing installation: pip 7.1.2
        Uninstalling pip-7.1.2:
          Successfully uninstalled pip-7.1.2
    Exception:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 211, in main
        # and when it is done, isinstance is not needed anymore
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 311, in run


      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 657, in install
        )
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 729, in comm
    it_uninstall
        for name, value in config.items('console_scripts'):
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_uninstall.py", line 152, in co
    mmit
        )
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 49, in wrap
    ped_f
        return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 212, in cal
    l
        raise attempt.get()
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 247, in get

        six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\retrying.py", line 200, in cal
    l
        attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 90, in rmtree

        try:
      File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
        rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
      File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 247, in rmtree
        rmtree(fullname, ignore_errors, onerror)
      File "c:\python27\lib\shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
        onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
      File "c:\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 102, in rmtre
    e_errorhandler
        onerror=rmtree_errorhandler)
    WindowsError: [Error 5] Zugriff verweigert: 'c:\\user\\appdata\\local\\
    temp\\pip-3gcbbo-uninstall\\python27\\scripts\\pip.exe'
```

Would be great, if someone could help me.

Comment: "Zugriff verweigert" means "Access denied", so I guess you don't have permission to overwrite `'c:\\users\\gerald\\appdata\\local\\
    temp\\pip-3gcbbo-uninstall\\python27\\scripts\\pip.exe'`, or perhaps you do and  your OS has a problem overwriting files which are currently being executed.

Comment: try with : python -m pip install --upgrade pip --no-cache-dir

Comment: thank you for your help. I tried several things. Finally "pip install --upgrade setuptools" worked

Comment: If it is access denied, then use try to run your command prompt as Administrator, Start Menu->Run/Search->cmd, right-click ->Run as Administrator.